# Meaning of 'as saying'

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, adverbs

"He was quoted as saying there would be further delays."

Here what is the meaning of **as saying**?

Like, Someone quoted him that, "he was saying— there would be further delays.(**saying** as participle)

Or,

Someone quoted him that, he said — there would be further delays. (**saying** as gerund(verbal noun))

I can't figuring out whether '**saying** has been used in this sentence as participle or gerund(verbal noun).

Because **as** could be used as both preposition and adverb.

I also can't figuring out here that **as** has been used in above sentence as preposition or adverb ?

I have doubt on above context for long time. So, help me to understand this...

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider 'quoted as saying' as a complete, fixed-phrase, idiom, and that 'as' in this and similar uses is equivalent to 'to be'. It is being used as (!) a preposition showing the characteristic or quality of something - *this book is described as a tragedy*.

He was quoted as (= to be) saying there would be further delays.

My purchase of a large dog was regarded by my family as (= to be) a mistake.

My cousin is described as a genius

> **quote as saying**
>
> **idiom**
>
> to report or say (the exact words) of (someone) —usually used in the
> form *be quoted as*
>
> *He was quoted as saying there would be further delays.*

[Quote as saying (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quote%20as%20saying)

Comment: But There should grammatical explanation here.

Comment: @Ansh The other important word here, besides "idiom," is "phrase." Sometimes chunks of words act together as if they're one word, and it's not always possible to parse each one of them to a specific role; it's better to consider the role of the phrase.

Comment: "as" implies something that *appeared* to be true or something you were told was true (e.g. a quote), while "to be" more strongly implies truth or reality.

Comment: @StuartF - I am not sure about that. 'Quoted to be saying' seems sufficiently distanced.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, if 'as' is acting as preposition over, then 'saying' should be noun? Since, noun is used after preposition.